# The domain (C:/../index.html) that redirected to Checkout is not enabled in the dashboard [Stripe API]

Tags: javascript, html, web, stripe-payments

When using the checkout button for stripe payments in index.html, stripe throws me the following error:

```
The domain (C:/../index.html) that redirected to Checkout is not enabled in the dashboard
```

I read the docs and they told that we should add the checkout domains in this URL: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout, so I add the index.html but it is still the same

I don't understand what is happening, help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You provided a local file (`C:/../index.html`) as your success URL for your Checkout Session rather than a URL that's accessible on the internet. Checkout needs a real URL for that to work.

The error is specifically notifying you that when using client-only Checkout you must first provide a list of domains that you intend to use in your dashboard settings: https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/checkout

Bear in mind that you must provide a real URL and not a path to a file on your system.

Comment: so how can I test the button?

Comment: For testing, you'll need to run a server locally and then provide that URL. For instance http://localhost:8080/index.html